# name of channel in rabitmq consumer using celery

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, amqp, message-bus

I have setup, where we are using [celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/) and [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com) to schedule our task based on data.

When we create multiple consumer to same queue, it create `bindings` and web portal shows the consumer IP in `channel` column.

[image: Consumer Channel]

Its hard to find the `consumer` based on `IP:PORT`. Is there any way in celery configuration, where we can give the name of these channel? by which we know, which host or machine consume this message.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the host name, is there a reason why you cannot just use

> socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)

Comment: Saheed, I want to give name for channel instead of IP, as we give name to the queue, silly, want to know if there is way to name the channel.

Comment: Do you mean channels or connections? Connections can be named, but AFAIK, channels cannot. Further, you said you needed the name of the host, which is what my answer gives. I think you may need to review what you said versus what you meant...